# Select from Many to Many tables in SQL Sever

Tags: view, sql-server-2012

I have two tables in SQL Server 2012 , that Many to Many (n to m) relationship established between them:

table1 and table2

[image]
[image]

I need to have a View or Query (or SP) from **table2** that will show the following result:

[image]

Is it possible to write this query?

Comment: What you have shown does not demonstrate a "many to many" relationship between the two tables.

Comment: Also, no join will result in the values your list shows, i.e. why are `Table1_Id` and `Price` empty for `RowID` =`151`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.RowID, b.Table1_Id, a.Price
FROM table2 a
INNER JOIN table1 b
ON a.Table1_Id=b.Table1_ID
```